# Twig crashes when baking models or other things

Tags: cakephp, twig, cakephp-4.x

I have installed a new cakephp-4 (4.2.x) app skeleton on a Windows machine under xampp (PHP8).

when I try to bake something, whether everything (all), models or just controllers, Twig crashes with an exception.

```
Exception: Class "templates" not found
In [C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php(359) : eval()'d code, line 16]

2021-09-01 10:11:27 Error: [Error] Class "templates" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php(359) : eval()'d code on line 16
Stack Trace:
- C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php:359
- C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php:309
- C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\cakephp\twig-view\src\View\TwigView.php:301
- C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php:1134
- C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\cakephp\bake\src\View\BakeView.php:97
- C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\cakephp\bake\src\Utility\TemplateRenderer.php:101
- C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\cakephp\bake\src\Command\SimpleBakeCommand.php:108
- C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\cakephp\bake\src\Command\SimpleBakeCommand.php:89
- C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Console\BaseCommand.php:179
- C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Console\CommandRunner.php:336
- C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Console\CommandRunner.php:172
- C:\xampp\htdocs\...\bin\cake.php:12
```

the exception thrown inside an eval call. If i dump the eval()-code, this is the result:

```
 1: <?php
 2:
 3: use Twig\Environment;
 4: use Twig\Error\LoaderError;
 5: use Twig\Error\RuntimeError;
 6: use Twig\Extension\SandboxExtension;
 7: use Twig\Markup;
 8: use Twig\Sandbox\SecurityError;
 9: use Twig\Sandbox\SecurityNotAllowedTagError;
10: use Twig\Sandbox\SecurityNotAllowedFilterError;
11: use Twig\Sandbox\SecurityNotAllowedFunctionError;
12: use Twig\Source;
13: use Twig\Template;
14:
15: /* C:\xampp\htdocs\...\vendor\cakephp\bake\templates\bake\Model\table.twig */
16: class __TwigTemplate_fd9d396735f9f3d92fb5494e152b7590e0d7311301188596d65a6f6ce132750f extends templates
17: {
18:     private $source;
19:     private $macros = [];
```

Line 16 is the problem (there is no class `templates`).
I don't know enough about twig to look for the fault; Googling didn't help.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the cause of the error?

Comment: Did you change the default [`base_template_class`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html#base-template-class) by chance?

Comment: No I have not. That can not be it.

Comment: The code (`\Twig\Node\ModuleNode`) originally writes `extends Template`. With CakePHP 4 the `Template` folder name was changed to `templates`. And now your compiled twig templates do extend `templates`. Coincidence?

Comment: Hmh; Possibly not a coincidence. If I add (very dirty) $content = str_replace ("extends templates", "extends Template", $content); then it works fine. But someone must have noticed that before. I think I'll open an issue in the CakePhp Git.

Comment: What I'm trying to hint to, is that it's maybe something that you did, like for example running the upgrade tool incorrectly, or even manually doing a search & replace. Twig's vendor code in a clean new project looks perfectly correct to me, and baking works as expected.

Comment: hmh, nop: I have installed a new cakephp-4 (4.2.x) app skeleton... But i will try a new installation, before create an issue...